# How can I make a method private in an interface?

Tags: c#, interface

I have this interface:

```
public interface IValidationCRUD
{
    public ICRUDValidation IsValid(object obj);
    private void AddError(ICRUDError error);
}
```

But when I use it (Implement Interface, automatic generation of code), I get this:

```
public class LanguageVAL : IValidationCRUD
{   
    public ICRUDValidation IsValid(object obj)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void AddError(ICRUDError error)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }   
}
```

The method AddError is public and not private as I wanted.

How can I change this?

Comment: I'm surprised this compiles, I'm sure when I've been on 'auto pilot' typing out an interface and added 'public' without thinking the compiler has complained at me.

Comment: It doesn't compile. You can't have private methods in an interface, and you're not even allowed to specify public as that is implicit for all members of an interface.

Comment: I just wrote the interface and after tried to used it on the other class. Visual Studio din't compile it.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

An interface can only have public methods. You might consider using an abstract base class with a protected abstract method `AddError` for this. The base class can then implement the `IValidationCRUD` interface, but only after you have removed the private method.

like this:

```
public interface IValidationCRUD
{
    ICRUDValidation IsValid(object obj);
}

public abstract class ValidationCRUDBase: IValidationCRUD {
    public abstract ICRUDValidation IsValid(object obj);
    protected abstract void AddError(ICRUDError error);
}
```

Comment: A (well formed) interface can only have public methods. Interestingly, the CLR supports constants, fields, and even static (type) constructors for interfaces. This is because an interface is implemented just as any other type definition.

Comment: Fields on interfaces are not CLS-Compliant though, no?

Comment: Correct. CLS-compliant interfaces cannot contain static members because languages such as c# are not able to define or access them.

Comment: @RobertVenables: What would be the effect of an interface that was declared with internal members?  If the behavior was that references of that interface type could be exchanged with outside code, but only the assembly declaring the interface could implement it, that would be useful behavior.

Comment: @supercat I think that's what i would use an abstract base class for, since that is part of the implementation, and that's not what interfaces are for.

Comment: @Botz3000: The problem with an abstract class is that any class that inherits from one can't inherit from, or be substitutable for, any other class which isn't related to the abstract class.  Thus, at least to my mind, one should favor interfaces over abstract classes except in cases where one needs to share the inner workings of the class.

Comment: @supercat I thought you meant something like fields. Do you mean a special kind of visibility like in "callpublicbutimplementinternal void InterfaceMethod();"?

Comment: @Botz3000: Nothing so fancy.  If the definition for an interface (in CIL) specifies that a particular member is internal, what would .net do if an effort is made to implement the interface within the assembly where it is defined (or a "friend" to that assembly) or if an effort is made to declare or use a variable of that type outside the assembly?  I've never worked in CIL, so I can't conduct such an experiment myself, but it would seem pretty easy to test in CIL.

Comment: @supercat The CLI doesn't allow an interface to have internal instance members. It says so in section 8.9.4 of the standard: "all members of an interface shall have public accessibility". Also, when you try to compile CIL code using ilasm, it'll throw an error "Non-public instance method in interface". *static* interface members, which the CLI allows, can be internal. Just tested it.

Comment: @Botz3000: Thanks for the info. If an interface has static members, can other languages use it? One thing I've long wished for would be a means by which an interface `IFoo` could specify that if it has a member e.g. `void Bar(int boz);`, a compiler which is producing an implementation of `IFoo` but doesn't find that member could check for a suitably-tagged static member `static void Bar(IFoo it, int boz);` and auto-generate `void IFoo.Bar(int boz) {IFoo.Bar(this, boz);}`  Such a feature could save a few lines of code on every `IEnumerable<T>` implementation if...

Comment: @Botz3000: ...compilers could auto-generate the code for the non-generic `GetEnumerator()` method to call a static method which would in turn chain to the generic one.  Further, an `IEnhancedList<T>` could include a variety of methods like `Sort` and `InsertRange` without burdening implementations. If an implementing class could perform `InsertRange` faster than a sequence of individual item inserts, it could implement that method; otherwise, it could defer to a default implementation.  I wonder how hard it would be to add such a feature?

Comment: @supercat Actually, extension methods already provide something similar. That's the concept used by Linq. If a collection doesn't implement e.g. `Where`, then the static extension method `Enumerable.Where` is used. If it implements the method itself, then that implementation is preferred at compile time. This and the ability to create abstract base classes is probably enough for most developers. Adding default implementations to interfaces would unnecessarily complicate the language and break the clean separation of interfaces and implementation.

Comment: @supercat I don't think implementing it would be that hard. In theory, you could mark your interface with an attribute linking to a method providing the default implementation, then, before the compiler complains about a missing implementation, it could check for that attribute on the interface, and, if present, implement the method by calling the method. So probably not hard, but i don't think there has been that much demand for such a feature, so noone bothered to implement it.

Comment: @Botz3000: Had such a feature existed in .net 2.0 and the related languages, it would probably have saved literally a million lines of code by now, in `IEnumerable<T>` implementations alone (with the compiler auto-generating `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {return EnumerableHelpers<T>.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator(this);}` (assuming `static class EnumerableHelpers<T> {static class IEnumerable {static IEnumerator GetEnumerator(IEnumerable<T> it) {return it.GetEnumerator();}}}`.)  Adding it now wouldn't recoup the time spent writing `GetEnumerator` chain methods, but...

Comment: ...it would still be helpful going forward.  Further, while run-time duck-typing (as is done by the extension method `IEnumerable<T>.Count()`) is hardly unworkable, the pattern adds an extra layer of run-time binding; while that may be the only practical workaround for something whose need was not foreseen when the interface was written, that doesn't mean it's a good pattern in cases where the author of an interface could imagine cases where some classes could benefit from custom implementations of an interface, but most classes would want to use a "stock" one.

Comment: @supercat There are lots of features that would be nice-to-have for some developers. But i don't think it would add enough value to justify the costs. How do you know which default implementation of a given interface is used (you can't edit IEnumerable)? You'd need to add the default-imp-attribute to an extension method. And what if there are multiple choices? Thinking about it, such a feature might require quite a bit of work just for saving 3 lines of code (which calling a utility method requires) for some developers, and that work should better be spent on more useful features (like async).

Comment: @Botz3000: I would expect that when Microsoft adds support for such an attribute, the would add the appropriate attribute to things like IEnumerable (as they did with covariance); alternatively, they could perhaps permit an interface to contain a static class of a certain special name, members of which would satisfy like-named interface members, with some slight name mangling for events and properties. As for whether it's worth it, there are two big value aspects: (1) three lines of code, repeated enough thousands of times, starts to add up; (2) if an interface...

Comment: ...would benefit by having member for complex a operation which can be performed with primitives, but which some implementations could do better via other means, the development system shouldn't discourage its inclusion by burdening the authors of implementations which can't exploit it; (3) if the call-to-static-method wrappers could be generated by the JIT, a type like `IList<T>` could inherit from a covariant supertype `IReadableList<out T>`, with `IList<T>` implementations automatically supporting the latter.  Others may disagree, but to me those seem like nice wins.

Comment: You can have private methods in interfaces since C# 8
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59455727/private-members-in-interface

Answer (score 37):

A private member makes no sense as part of an interface. An interface is there to define a set of methods, a role, an object must always implement. Private methods, on the other hand, are implementation details, not intended for public consumption.

Comment: You can't. Specifying an access modifier (private or public) results in a compilation error.

Comment: Interfaces should be seen as a mechanism to enforce the contract a class makes towards users of the class. It guarantees that X,Y,Z,... methods will always be available to be used by external users of the class. What is annoying though, is that sometimes, you want to save yourself the trouble of implementing methods that you want programmers of the class to have access to when implementing the class itself. You can do this by inheriting another concrete or abstract class, but because C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, you can not mix and match, so you'll need to resort to composition.

Answer (score 8):

An interface cannot contain private fields.
However, the closest behavior to "private fields" you can achieve is by using explicit implementation (explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Its not a valid scenario in real case, but still you can achieve through explicit implementation of interface

```
 interface Itest
 {
      void functiona();
      void functionb();
 }
class child : Itest
{
     public void functiona()
     {
     }
     void Itest.functionb()
     {
     }
}
```

here functionb() is explicitly implimented so if you created the object of class child you wont get functionb()

Answer (score 4):

Since c# 8.0 you can define *private* methods in interfaces. Here is the link to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/interfaces)

Since *private* interface members *won't be accessible in an implementing class* you'll have to provide a *default* implementation for such member, otherwise such code won't compile.

A real use case for such method may be a refactoring of another default method in an interface.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of an interface:

> The CLR also allows an interface to contain static
>   methods, static fields, constants, and static constructors. However, a CLS-compliant interface must not have any of these static members because some programming languages aren’t able to define or access them. In fact, C# prevents an interface from defining any static members. In addition, the CLR doesn’t allow an interface to contain any instance fields or instance constructors.

These are the rules of an interface and you can't do anything on that :)

These are not allowed

```
interface IIValidationCRUD
{
    static ICRUDValidation IsValid(object obj); //error
}

interface IIValidationCRUD
{
    public ICRUDValidation IsValid(object obj); //error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using :

```
void IValidationCRUD.AddError(ICRUDError error)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Instead of

```
public void AddError(ICRUDError error)
{
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

Sorry to join in too late.