# How to hide a method, which is part of an interface implementation within a base class, from classes that derive from the base class?

Tags: c#, interface, derived-class, base-class, method-hiding

I have the following structure:

```
public class Foo : FooBaseNamespace.FooBase
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Register("abc");
    }
}

public class FooBase : IFoo
{
    public FooBase()
    {

    }

    public void Register(string id)
    {

    }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    void Register(string id);
}
```

Please note that `FooBase` and `IFoo` reside in namespace `FooNamespace` but `Foo` resides in a different namespace but has access to `FooNameSpace`.

My question is, can I adjust the code so that method `Register(string id)` is hidden from any classes that derive from `FooBase`?

Thanks

Comment: [Sealed methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645769(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: @Sayse, how, if the method is an interface implementation?

Comment: @Sayse That doesn't change the fact the interface implementation will be `public` and therefore accessible. I don't think overriding is the issue..

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383434/how-can-i-make-a-method-private-in-an-interface

Comment: Precisely why I didn't post it as an answer, I'm not on a machine with  visual studio and not able to check it.. just pointing in a direction.  The way I read the question is to try and stop inherited classes of `FooBase` from overriding the method

Comment: Voting up question, because I learned something [new](http://dotnetfiddle.net/z0nPbL) today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really don't understand why you're implementing `IFoo` if you want to then hide that, and I think your modelling is not really correct.

See the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) for more info.

> Substitutability is a principle in object-oriented programming. It
>   states that, in a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then
>   objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S (i.e.,
>   objects of type S may substitute objects of type T) without altering
>   any of the desirable properties of that program (correctness, task
>   performed, etc.).

You could contain an `IFoo` implementation within your `FooBase` object (i.e. use composition) and delegate e.g.

```
public class FooBase {
   private IFoo hiddenFoo;
}
```

or perhaps use multiple interfaces e.g. `IRegisterable` alongside `IFoo`, where `IRegisterable` provides the `Register()` method and `IFoo` provides everything else. You can selectively reference `IRegisterable` as required.

Separating your interface definitions into interfaces providing distinct functions is a powerful means to giving objects different functionality depending on how they're referenced (e.g. one DAO can implement both `IReadable` and `IWriteable` and that functionality is exposed separately to different clients)

Comment: I implement `IFoo` to define a contract for the base class but I do not wish to extend such contract to the classes that derive from the base class. I guess my question extends to the general case. Can interface implementations only extend to a base class that derives from such interface but not further down?

Comment: I would be concerned in that case that the modelling is correct. I would expect that derived classes could be substituted with no change in the client (consuming) code

Comment: I am not sure I fully agree my specific use case necessarily points to incorrect modeling. Would it not make a lot of sense to provide a contract for a base class and let it go about to do the work promised by the contract (the interface) and let classes that derive from base not worry about the work which the base class performs and rather go about their own defined task? The classes that derive from base would access properties that are manipulated within base.

Comment: could you please elaborate what you mean with "is a powerful means to giving objects different functionality depending on how they're referenced". How can I have base class derive from 2 different interfaces but only expose methods of one interface to classes that derive from base? Or am I misunderstanding something and you are simply saying that what I try to achieve is impossible?

Comment: I could implement a class DaoImpl which implements the interfaces IWriteable and IReadable. I can then expose that to clients (*not* subclasses) as an IReadable or an IWriteable. Depending on how the class is exposed (readable or writeable) then the different capabilities are available to a client e.g. my class could implement the writeable functionality but be exposed to some clients simply as readable

Comment: Thanks Brian, upon reading up on Liskov I better understand what you were trying to say. For the time being I leave the method exposed to any derived classes while I will think about a potentially different structure.